# How can we access objects value that is nested inside an object with integer property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
hi = [ { 0: { symbol: "asdf" , name:"adad"} }]
```

How will you access symbol property here in JS

`console.log(hi[0])`  outputs `{ symbol: "asdf" , name:"adad"}`
but
`console.log(hi[0].symbol)` throws the error that symbol is undefined

Answer (score 1):

`hi` is an array. First you need to access the object so `hi[0]` will provide the first object. Then access the object using the key which is `0` like below

```js
const hi = [{
  0: {
    symbol: "asdf",
    name: "adad"
  }
}];

console.log(hi[0][0].symbol)
```

Comment: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

`hi` variable is an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) so you have to access the first element of the array first, then the [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) property:

```js
hi = [ { 0: { symbol: "asdf" , name:"adad"} }]

console.log(hi[0][0].symbol)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
console.log(hi[0][0].symbol)
```

Comment: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
hi = [ { 0: { symbol: "asdf" , name:"adad"} }]
```

hi[0][0].symbol is right.

```
console.log(hi[0]) => 0: {symbol: "asdf", name: "adad"}

console.log(hi[0][0]) => {symbol: "asdf", name: "adad"}

console.log(hi[0][0].symbol) => "asdf"
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.